# How to calculate factorial in Theano

Tags: python, theano, factorial

Here is a simple example.

```
import theano 
v = theano.tensor.scalar("variable") 
factorial = ? 
# Calculate factorial of v , like numpy.math.factorial(v), but it didn't work, 
# Actually it should be a integer as a parameter of numpy.math.factorial function 
result = theano.function([v], factorial)
```

There is few useful information on Internet. Something I found like 
http://matthewrocklin.com/blog//work/2013/08/14/SymPy-Theano-part-4
which told me it belonged to "the future work", which means there is no solution for this problem.
How could that possible? I mean is there no body need calculate factorial in your theano project?
I had this problem when I designed a RBM with Poisson conditional possibility which needs calculate factorial of visible units in the energy function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer that we use gamma function to solve the factorial problem.
:( Sorry for bothering everybody!
Here is the detail:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/theano-users/ytqep8AickA/cE7QeJZxXzUJ

So here should be:

```
import theano 
v = theano.tensor.scalar("variable") 
factorial = theano.tensor.gamma(v)
# Calculate factorial of v , like numpy.math.factorial(v), but it didn't work, 
# Actually it should be a integer as a parameter of numpy.math.factorial function 
result = theano.function([v], factorial)
```

Comment: Actually, factorial(v) is gamma(v+1).

Answer (score 0):

```
def factorial(x):
    y = x-1
    temp = x*y
    it = y-1
    for i in range(it):
        y -= 1
        temp = temp*y
    print temp
```

Here is the edited solution without the Boolean operators. I know you found another answer but this may be helpful to you as well as others in the future.

Comment: Theano variable like scalar doesn't support boolean operation, like y in your code. I have found the solution thanks.

Comment: Thanks guy! I really appreciated.